# How to redirect to the fastest responding website in an array of websites in PHP?

Tags: php, asyncsocket, php-socket

I have an online function which needs to connect to the quickest server out of a few websites in an array in PHP.

Here is how far I got. I used Fopen to check if the website is online and foreach to redirect to it. I figured that the quickest server would redirect first, but instead it just redirected the last item in the array in the URL.

Here's how far I got:

```
// The URLs to check in an Array.
$urls = ['website1.com', 'website2.com', 'website3.com'];
// Get the fastest server (the fastest server should redirect first)
foreach($urls as $proxy) {
    if ($socket = @ fsockopen($proxy, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30)) {
        header('Location: https://'.$proxy.'');
        fclose($socket);
    } else {}
}
echo 'Connecting to the fastest server...';
```

Thanks in advance. I look forward to seeing your replies :)

Comment: That would be synchronous, so the first will run, then the second. You need find a way of running this asynchronously. There is a library (personally untested) https://github.com/spatie/async

Comment: Well, one thing that jumps out, `header('Location: https://'.$proxy.''); fclose($socket);` switch these around and call `exit;` after `header` header doesn't end script execution, so it can cause UN-expected behaviour.  Also you can't redirect with header if you send any output, I cant tell by what you posted if you did or not, but it's often overlooked.  Also there is no need for that empty string `.'')`

Comment: I suspect your code is based in two incorrect assumptions: that `fsockopen()` in PHP behaves like XMLHttpRequest in JavaScript and `header()` stops script execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that Php does not provide a callback-like option to receive a succesful or failed connection on socket asynchronously.

Anyway there are great libs for Php out there. I'm also interested on this feature for Php.
You could install with [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) the following lib [https://github.com/reactphp/socket](http://reactphp/socket)
seems pretty straight forward to use.

Find it slightly adapted to your case:

```
$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$connector = new React\Socket\Connector($loop);
$urls = ['website1.com', 'website2.com', 'website3.com'];
foreach($urls as $proxy) {

  $socket = new React\Socket\Server($proxy, $loop);

  $socket->on('connection', function (ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    header('Location: https://'.$proxy.'');
    $conn->close();
  });
});

$loop->run();
```

Good luck!

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks for your contribution :)